# Why my drf-swagger drf-yasg api documentation is not categorized according to models?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, documentation, swagger-ui

although I have used same setting for both projects for documentation. Their documentation view is different. I want view like first one, Where api is categorized according to models.

**urls.py** - for both

```
from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view

schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="Nepal Hearing & Speech Care Center - Nepal",
        default_version="v1",
        description="API Documentation",
        terms_of_service="2022",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="info@merakitechs.com"),
        license=openapi.License(name="Private Project"),
    ),
    public=False,
)


urlpatterns = (
    [
        path(
            "doc",
            schema_view.with_ui("swagger", cache_timeout=0),
            name="schema-ui",
        ),
]
```

You can check photos for both Projects:

*Project 1*

[image: Project 1 (Required)]

*Project 2*

[image: Project 2 (to be changed)]

Answer (score 0):

```
@swagger_auto_schema(tags=['my_apis'])
class DepartmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Department.objects.all()
    #filter_class = 
    #filter_backends = (SearchFilter, OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    search_fields = []
    ordering_fields = []
    ordering = []
    http_method_names = ["options", "head", "post", "get", "patch"]
    
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        serializer_class = DepartmentListSerializer
        if self.request.method == "GET":
            if self.action == "list":
                serializer_class = DepartmentListSerializer
            else: 
                serializer_class = DepartmentRetrieveSerializer
        if self.request.method == "POST":
            serializer_class = DepartmentCreateSerializer
        elif self.request.method == "PATCH":
            serializer_class = DepartmentPatchSerializer
        
        return serializer_class
```

I changed my view to this. But still same issue.

Comment: This isn't an answer, further information should be included in the questions via edits. Keep in mind a second failed attempt at debugging isn't further information either.